# Permissions to write a file from SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to save a XML file from SQL. I'm doing something like:

```
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQLCmd VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT  @FileName = 'D:\ProductsList.xml'
SELECT  @db='MyBase.dbo.'

SELECT  @SQLCmd = 'bcp "SELECT '+@db+'ArticleName FROM '+@db+' ARTICLES' +
                   ' FOR XML PATH(''Product''),ELEMENTS, ROOT(''Products''), TYPE "' +
                   ' queryout '+@FileName +' -w -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME 

EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd
```

It works okay for me one one sql server but fails one another. I get message "Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file".

Bcp,queryout, cmdshell are unfortunately all new for me.

I'm reading a lot of websites and all they have some interesting information but I really don't know how to begin.

They say - add permissions for the user running the script. But who is this user if not me? ;) Is there some "automatic" Windows user created for running SQL Server  or what? Where can I see this user and configure his rights so it can save my file?

Or maybe there are some other issues with bcp and cmdshell that I should to know?

Big thanks for any help. I'm really stuck :(

Comment: Are you able to create any file manually on D:\ ?

Comment: It would be much simpler to do this from a batch file or script outside SQL Server. Using `xp_cmshell` is usually a bad idea because there are many potential permissions and security issues with it.

Comment: Okay, I solved it myself. When I perform actions with xp_cmdshell I don't do it as "myself" -the user which I used to log into Windows. Instead I'm working as some user called "mssqlserver" in my case. Check **xp_cmdshell 'whoami'** to see it. After a long despaired seach I found this link and it helped me with all my problems: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/9e6bb2de-8fd0-45de-ab02-d59bbe05f72e/